# Windows service TCP communication in local network

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, tcp

I've been trying to set up a service that runs in the background and communicates with a Server via TCP. I'm using the .NET Core to set up a TCPListener and, on another device, try to remotely connect via a TCPClient. If i use this outside of a service, in a user executed programm, it works just fine. However, if i start my service, the port im listening to only receives messages from 127.0.0.1, not from the local network.

I suspect there's some permission the service needs to accept network communication, but this is not really my field of expertise. Any advice?

There's no error message. Using Wireshark i confirmed that theres an incoming TCP request on the host, but no connection gets established with my Service.

Thanks in advance o/)

Edit:
I found out that it works if i disable the public firewall on the host PC. But im not really proficient with reading and interpreting the logs. the relevant sections read as follows:

## Firewall Log output

```
Fields: date time action protocol src-ip dst-ip src-port dst-port size tcpflags tcpsyn tcpack tcpwin icmptype icmpcode info path
                                                                                                                                                                                                2019-08-29 15:43:58 DROP UDP 192.168.7.98 192.168.7.255 34638 15600 63 - - - - - - - RECEIVE
2019-08-29 15:44:01 ALLOW UDP 192.168.7.117 192.168.7.70 137 137 0 - - - - - - - SEND
2019-08-29 15:44:02 DROP TCP 192.168.7.46 192.168.7.117 49958 13000 52 S 1580866692 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE
2019-08-29 15:44:03 DROP UDP 192.168.7.62 192.168.7.255 57621 57621 72 - - - - - - - RECEIVE
2019-08-29 15:44:04 DROP UDP 192.168.7.98 192.168.7.255 54123 15600 63 - - - - - - - RECEIVE
2019-08-29 15:44:05 DROP TCP 192.168.7.46 192.168.7.117 49958 13000 52 S 1580866692 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE
2019-08-29 15:44:10 DROP UDP 192.168.7.98 192.168.7.255 58249 15600 63 - - - - - - - RECEIVE
2019-08-29 15:44:11 DROP TCP 192.168.7.46 192.168.7.117 49958 13000 52 S 1580866692 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE
```

(Important are the dropped packages with destination 192.168.7.117:13000.) Does anyone have an idea of how to read those and find out why it's blocking it, and how to stop it from doing so?

Comment: Look in the services control panel and tell us what user the service runs as

Comment: Can you add your Startup.cs?

Comment: Do not listen on the loopback 127.0.0.1.  May not always work.  Use for the endpoint IP.Any.  There is a host file that can be setup different so it doesn't work.   Also when you have multiple Network Cards only one may be forwarding incoming messages to 127.0.0.1.  IP.Any listens to all Network cards.

Comment: @CaiusJard I've tried running the service as LocalService, LocalSystem and NetworkService, didnt have an effect on it. If you're asking because of the permissions, i tried using "sc sdset <ServiceName>D:AR(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;IU)S:(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)" to give it general allowance on... well everything (im getting desperate by now), also no effect. :c

Comment: @jdweng the TCPListener i use works on IP.Any, 0.0.0.0:13000. using netstat it also shows up as such

Comment: Can you use net stat to determine any other well known service running on your machine and see if. You can reach that service from a remote computer?

Comment: Do you mean the 127.0.0.1 on netstat is 0.0.0.0?  The firewall usually just blocks by port number and/or by protocol.  Sometimes by the contents and IP but not usually.  You have to find the firewall setting.  It may be in your IE advance settings in the allow and disallow sections.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

The problem was the public firewall blocking service communication for that port. Easiely fixed by adding a two rules that allowed my  windows service to communicate with the assigned port number.